# Update Sql Server from Mysql

Tags: linked-server

We have a website that stores form data in a web hosted MySQL database. Whenever form data is entered into the MySQL server tables I need update all necessary tables on our local SQL Server database.

I have seen several articles that describe how to update MySQL using SQL Server triggers but nothing that goes the other way.

If I create a linked server and linked tables in SQL Server can I create a trigger on a MySQL table from the SQL Server management studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't "see" the SQL Server from within MySQL like you can in the reverse direction with a linked server.

The only way I can think of doing this is to create a [MySQL trigger that calls a User Defined Function that executes an external application](http://crazytechthoughts.blogspot.com/2011/12/call-external-program-from-mysql.html) and passes the new data to it. The external application would have to connect to the SQL Server database and push the data to it.

```
DELIMITER @@

CREATE TRIGGER Test_Trigger 
AFTER INSERT ON MyTable 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

DECLARE cmd CHAR(255);
DECLARE result int(10);
SET cmd=CONCAT('/usr/bin/php ', 'home/sync/send_to_sql_server.php f1=', NEW.f1, ' f2=', NEW.f2);
SET result = sys_exec(cmd);

END;
@@
DELIMITER ;
```